# Access elements of a list inside a function

Tags: r, for-loop, lm

I found a useful function that I have been using in R to access the F-statistic p-values from a linear model

```
lmp<-function(modelobject){

if(class(modelobject !="lm" stop ("Not an object of class 'lm ")
f<-(modelobject)$fstatistic
p<-pf(f[1],f[2],f[3],lower.tail=F)
attributes(p)<-NULL
return(p)

}
```

However, the data that I need to use this function is not an object of class lm rather a list with 12 elements. Each element of the list is the summary generated from lm.
Each summary in the list data, can be accessed using

```
data[[1]]$fstatistic
```

I want to change the function to loop over each element in the list and return the F-statistic p-value, I tried modifying the function to include a for loop,
    lmpmod<-function(modelobject){

```
for (i in 1:12) {
f<-(modelobject)[[i]]$fstatistic
p<-pf(f[1], f[2], f[3], lower.tail=F)
attributes(p)<-NULL
return(p)

}
}
```

but the output keeps over-writing itself.
Can anyone tell me how to modify this function so that I can access each element in the list  and calculate the F-statistic p-value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
lapply( data , function(x) { tmp <-  summary(x)$fstatistic ;
                             pf( tmp[1] , tmp[2] , tmp[3] , lower.tail = F )
                             } )
```

For example...

```
#  non-sensical lm!
set.seed(123)
y <- 1 + rnorm(10)

#  this makes a list of 5 lm's using the response data 'y'
data <- replicate( 5 , lm(  y ~ 1 + rnorm(10) ) , simpl = FALSE )

#  Call 'summary' on model object to calculate the f-statistic, and run 'pf' to get p-value
sapply( data , function(x) { f <- summary(x)$fstatistic ; pf(f[1], f[2], f[3], lower.tail=F) } )
     value      value      value      value      value 
0.53263166 0.03896285 0.70298727 0.57721440 0.45352619
```

Comment: That returns NULL values. I actually need the p-values from the fstatistic which is why I need to pass the function over the data.

Comment: I assume the problem stems from the fact that the way you are presently doing this, you call the summary method on the lm object when you access it, which is what generates the `f-statistic`. Using the raw mode fit doesn't do this. I'll edit....